# Correct datatype to store logical matrix in SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, matrix

I'm currently writing a OCR algorithm in Python and I'm extracting for each bitmap characters a point cloud of binary values to have a schematic representation of the character.
This point cloud can be represented as follow ;

```
[[0001001],
 [1001100],
 [0100101]]
```

My matrices are around 30 x 30 but this size can vary, so I was thinking about converting each binary line into an hexadecimal number and store this sequence of hexadecimal numbers into a `TEXT` datatype in my SQL database.

I also read information about bytearray but I can't figure how to 'convert' my logical matrix into a bytearray and then store this bytearray into a `VARBINARY` datatype in my database.

What would be the best datatype for a lightweight solution to store and search into this database ?

May the peace be with you all,